# Adding an empty line at the end of input

Tags: command-line, bash

I have some command which produces output with no new line at the end,
like this

```
Myprompt$ somecmd
dksfjdl
dsfjdlkfj
dsfjdkfj
dfjdkfjMyprompt$
```

Currently I overcome this by `somecmd | sed 's/$/\n/' | tr -s '\n'`
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just run echo after it, it should generate a newline

```
Myprompt$ somecmd ; echo
```

And If you need to feed it to something else, run it in a sub-shell:

```
Myprompt$ ( somecmd ; echo ) | someothercmd
```

Or.. as @camh points out, the subshell is actually not needed you can execute it with a command list in the current shell environment with:

```
Myprompt$ { somecmd ; echo ; } | someothercmd
```

Answer (score 3):

Feed it through some utility which read input in lines and output lines, like in `awk { print $0 }`.